Proof that $[\pi (x), (\nabla \phi (x'))^2] = [\pi (x), -\phi(x')\nabla^2 \phi (x')]$
On p.25 of Quantum Field Theory by Peskin and Schroeder, the time derivatives of the Klein-Gordon field and conjugate momentum field are evaluated as follows.

the following result is used
As part of the derivation of $\frac{\partial \pi(x)}{\partial t}$ (between the first and second lines of its evaluation) the following result is assumed:
$$[\pi (x), (\nabla \phi (x'))^2] = [\pi (x), -\phi(x')\nabla^2 \phi (x')]$$
I am trying to prove this expression (without resorting to ladder operator expressions), but I am not able to. Using $[AB,C]=A[B,C]+[A,C]B$, I get
$$[\pi (x), (\nabla \phi (x'))^2] = [\pi (x), \nabla \phi (x') \cdot \nabla \phi (x')]$$
$$ = - \nabla \phi (x') \cdot [\nabla \phi (x'), \pi (x)] - [\nabla \phi (x'), \pi (x)]  \cdot \nabla \phi (x')$$
But the only way I can evaluate these is if I expand the field expressions in terms of the ladder operators. Is there a result that Peskin & Schroeder are using that I am not aware of?

The result is "assumed" within the $\int !! d^3 x'$ integral where integration by parts is discretionary. Is this your conceptual problem?

Using the canonical equal time commutation relations solves your problem:$$\left[\frac{\partial \phi(\vec{x}^\prime,t)}{\partial x_k^\prime}, \pi(\vec{x},t)   \right] = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k^\prime}\left[\phi(\vec{x}^\prime, t), \pi(\vec{x},t) \right]= i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k^\prime} \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}^\prime-\vec{x}).$$
Applying this to the relevant term, one obtains
$$\begin{align}   &\left[\pi(\vec{x}, t), \int \! d^3x^\prime \, \phi(\vec{x}^\prime,t) \nabla_k^\prime \nabla_k^\prime \phi(\vec{x}^\prime,t)   \right] = \int \! d^3x^\prime \, \left[\pi(\vec{x},t), \phi(\vec{x}^\prime,t) \nabla_k^\prime \nabla_k^\prime \phi(\vec{x}^\prime,t)       \right] \\[5pt]
&= \int \! d^3 x^\prime \left\{ \left[ \pi(\vec{x},t),\phi(\vec{x}^\prime,t)\right]\nabla_k^\prime \nabla_k^\prime \phi(\vec{x}^\prime,t)+ \phi(\vec{x}^\prime,t) \left[ \pi(\vec{x},t) ,\nabla_k^\prime \nabla_k^\prime \phi(\vec{x}^\prime,t)  \right]  \right\}\\[5pt]
&=-i\int d^3x^\prime \, \left\{\delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{x}^\prime)    \nabla_k^\prime \nabla_k^\prime \phi(\vec{x}^\prime,t) +\phi(\vec{x}^\prime,t)\nabla_k^\prime \nabla_k^\prime \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{x}^\prime) \right\}\\[5pt]
&=-2i \int \! d^3x^\prime \, \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{x}^\prime) \nabla_k^\prime \nabla_k^\prime \phi(\vec{x}^\prime,t)=-2i\nabla_k \nabla_k \phi(\vec{x},t)=-2i \Delta \phi(\vec{x},t)\end{align}     $$

Thank you. But in this case I get $[\pi(x),(\nabla \phi (x'))^2]=[\pi(x),\nabla \phi (x')] \cdot \nabla \phi (x') + \nabla \phi (x') \cdot [\pi(x),\nabla \phi (x')] = \nabla [\pi(x), \phi (x')] \cdot \nabla \phi (x') + \nabla \phi (x') \cdot \nabla [\pi(x), \phi (x')] = - \nabla i \delta^{(3)}( \textbf{x}'-\textbf{x}) \cdot \nabla \phi (x') - \nabla \phi (x') \cdot \nabla i \delta^{(3)}( \textbf{x}'-\textbf{x})$.

I need the last expression to be equal to $2i \delta^{(3)}( \textbf{x}'-\textbf{x}) \nabla^{2} \phi (x')$, bu the two results aren't equivalent.

@pll04 As CosmasZachos had already told you, your expression is integrated over $d^3 x^\prime$ and you simply have to use integration by parts. Note also, that you should clearly distinguish $\nabla$ and $\nabla^\prime$, which is incorrectly done in your first comment.

@pll04 I have now added a detailed calculation in my answer.

Thank you! I am just confused about the first step on the last line. Since the delta function is a function of $x'$, shouldn't its Laplacian give something like this: $\nabla'{k} \nabla'{k} \delta^{(3)}(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x'})$
$= \nabla'^{2}\int \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^3}e^{i\textbf{p} \cdot (\textbf{x}-\textbf{x'})d^3 p$
$= -|\textbf{p}|^2 \delta^{(3)}(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x'})$

@pll04 The formula in your comment is unreadable. The first step in the last line of my answer uses the definition of the delta distribution: $\int dx^\prime \delta(x-x^\prime) f(x^\prime)= f(x)$.

I agree with the definition you provided, but I don't think it applies in this case, since the Laplacian operator is acting on the delta function. I don't see how we can make the Laplacian suddenly act on the phi field. Here is the formula I wrote above: $\nabla'{k} \nabla'{k} \delta^{(3)}(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x'})$ $=\nabla'^{2}\int \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^3}e^{i\textbf{p} \cdot (\textbf{x}-\textbf{x'})}d^3 p$ $= -|\textbf{p}|^2 \delta^{(3)}(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x'})$

@pll04 This is my last comment: In your last comment, $p$ is an integration variable, it cannot show up in the result. Your assertion is clearly wrong.

Good call, my last line is wrong, but my point still stands - you cannot use the definition of the delta function if an operator is acting on it. I should have written $\nabla'{k} \nabla'{k} \delta^{(3)} (\textbf{x} - \textbf{x}')$
$=  \int \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^3} |\textbf{p}|^2 e^{i\textbf{p} \cdot (\textbf{x} - \textbf{x}')} d^3 p$. Anyway, I appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions.

I found the full correct solution, so I thought I'd write out here.
We start with
$$[\pi(x), H_{KG}] = [\pi(x), \frac{1}{2} \int (\pi(x')^2 + (\nabla' \phi(x'))^2 + m^2 \phi(x')^2 ] $$
$$ = [\pi(x), \frac{1}{2} \int (\pi(x')^2 + (\nabla' \phi(x'))^2 + m^2 \phi(x')^2 )d^3 x'] $$
$$ = \frac{1}{2} \int [\pi(x),((\nabla' \phi(x'))^2 + m^2 \phi(x')^2 )] d^3 x'$$
because $[\pi(x),\pi(x')] = 0$. We can place the whole commutator inside the integral, because $\pi(x)$ is independent of $x'$. The term I was confused by is $\int [\pi(x),((\nabla' \phi(x'))^2] d^3 x$. Now, as pointed out by @CosmasZachos, we can use integration by parts to evaluate $\int ((\nabla \phi(x'))^2 d^3 x'$ as
$$\int ((\nabla \phi(x'))^2 d^3 x' = [\phi(x') \nabla' \phi(x')]_{V'} - \int \phi(x') \nabla'^2 \phi(x') d^3 x'$$
, where we can consider an infinite volume $V'$, at the boundaries of which $\phi(x') \rightarrow 0$, such that
$$\int ((\nabla \phi(x'))^2 d^3 x' = - \int \phi(x') \nabla'^2 \phi(x') d^3 x'.$$
Hence, the term $\int [\pi(x),((\nabla' \phi(x'))^2] d^3 x$ is given by
$$\int [\pi(x),((\nabla' \phi(x'))^2] d^3 x = - \int [\pi(x),\phi(x') \nabla'^2 \phi(x')] d^3 x'$$
In order to evaluate the commutator $\int [\pi(x),\phi(x') \nabla'^2 \phi(x')] d^3 x'$ we use
$$[AB,C] = A[B,C]+[A,C]B$$
giving
$$\int [\pi(x),\phi(x') \nabla'^2 \phi(x')] d^3 x' = \int [\pi(x),\phi(x')] \nabla'^2 \phi(x') d^3 x' + \int \phi(x')[\pi(x),\nabla'^2 \phi(x')] d^3 x'$$
The first term can be easily evaluated using the commutation relation $[\pi(x),\phi(x')] = -i \delta^{(3)} (\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}')$, giving
$$\int [\pi(x),\phi(x')] \nabla'^2 \phi(x') d^3 x' = \int -i \delta^{(3)} (\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}') \nabla'^2 \phi(x') d^3 x'$$
$$= -i\nabla^2 \phi(x)$$
Up to here, my derivation is the same as the one shown in @Hyperon's answer. However, the second term cannot be evaluated in the same way, since the Laplacian operator is acting on the delta function as:
$$\int \phi(x')[\pi(x),\nabla'^2 \phi(x')] d^3 x' = \int \phi(x') \nabla'^2 [\pi(x), \phi(x')] d^3 x'$$
$$= -i \int \phi(x') \nabla'^2 \delta^{(3)} (\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}') d^3 x'$$
Hence, it is incorrect to apply the definition of the delta function here ($\int \delta (x-x') f(x') dx' = f(x)$). In general,
$$\int f(x') \nabla'^2 \delta^{(3)} (\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}') d^3 x' \neq \nabla^2 f(x).$$
Instead, we simplify this expression by integrating by parts twice.
$$\int \phi(x')[\pi(x),\nabla'^2 \phi(x')] d^3 x' = \int \phi(x') \nabla'^2 [\pi(x), \phi(x')] d^3 x'$$
$$= [\phi(x') \nabla' [\pi(x), \phi(x')]_{V'} - \int \nabla' [\pi(x), \phi(x')] \cdot \nabla' \phi(x').$$
By the same boundary conditions argument as above, we can set $[\phi(x') \nabla' [\pi(x), \phi(x')]_{V'}=0$, giving
$$\int \phi(x')[\pi(x),\nabla'^2 \phi(x')] d^3 x' = - \int \nabla' [\pi(x), \phi(x')] \cdot \nabla' \phi(x').$$
Integrating by parts a second time gives
$$\int \phi(x')[\pi(x),\nabla'^2 \phi(x')] d^3 x' = -[[\pi(x), \phi(x')] \nabla' \phi(x')]_{V'} + \int [\pi(x), \phi(x') \nabla'^2 \phi(x')] d^3 x'$$
$$= \int [\pi(x), \phi(x')] \nabla'^2 \phi(x') d^3 x'$$
$$= \int -i \delta^{(3)} (\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}')] \nabla'^2 \phi(x') d^3 x'$$
$$= -i \nabla^2 \phi(x)$$
, where $[[\pi(x), \phi(x')] \nabla' \phi(x')]_{V'} = 0$.
Combining these results we get
$$\int [\pi(x),\phi(x') \nabla'^2 \phi(x')] d^3 x' = -2i \nabla^2 \phi(x)$$
, hence
$$\int [\pi(x), \frac{1}{2} (\nabla'^2 \phi(x'))^2] d^3 x' = i \nabla^2 \phi(x)$$
as required.
